# Why can’t I seem to combine :visited and ::after?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I am writing some CSS that should create some generated content.

```css
.foo:visited::after {
  display: inline;
  content: " visited";
 }
```

However, it has no effect.

If I change the selector to just `.foo::after`, it works.

Similarly, my styles for `.foo:visited` take effect.

The Safari web inspector is even showing my styles for `:visited::after` as if they are in effect!

Why can’t I see my generated content?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Browsers limit the styles you are allowed to modify on a visited link, and even lie to you if you query for the current color of the link with JavaScript.

Why?

Because otherwise, you, at `scumbag-advertising.example.com`, can run a bunch of JavaScript to see what websites (or at least URLs) are in the browser’s history!

For more, see [`:visited` on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:visited) and [this longer explanation of how this privacy hole was closed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Privacy_and_the_:visited_selector):

> Historically, the CSS `:visited` selector has been a way for sites to query the user's history, by using `getComputedStyle()` or other techniques to walk through the user's history to figure out what sites the user has visited. This can be done quickly, and makes it possible not only to determine where the user has been on the web, but can also be used to guess a lot of information about a user's identity.

A number of years ago, browsers patched up this hole by limiting changes and lying about color.